# Importing CSV files creates a clipboard error

Tags: excel, vba, clipboard

I have a macro that imports a bunch of csv files into a spreadsheet. The csvs are updated daily adding more files every day. Currently I'm up to about 130. I open each csv copy the entire contents and paste tham all onto the same worksheet. I get an "There's a large amount of data on the clipboard....Do you want to keep it" error. I click 'no' and the macro continues. At first I got the message after every file. I added code that should dump the clipboard contents after each file is pasted but before it's closed. Now I get the message after about 40-50 files but I shouldn't be getting it at all. I thought the code does that but I still get the error message. I can't find the problem or anything I need to add through google. How do I ensure the clipboard is cleared before moving on to the next file?

```
Option Explicit

Public Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Public Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
```

```
Sub ImportData()

Dim i As Variant
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim clastrow As Long
Dim filePath As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim count As Long
Dim importRange As Range
Dim currentData As Range
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim cws As Excel.Worksheet

Set cws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw_Data")

lastrow = cws.Cells(Rows.count, "a").End(xlUp).Row

If lastrow >= 5 Then
    Set currentData = cws.Range("a5:r" & lastrow)
Else
    Set currentData = cws.Range("a5:r" & 6)
End If

currentData.ClearContents

filePath = "C:\Local_Path"
fileName = Dir(filePath & "*.csv")

count = 1
Do While fileName <> ""

    Set wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open(filePath & fileName)
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

    lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, "a").End(xlUp).Row

    Set importRange = ws.Range("a2:f" & lastrow)

    importRange.Copy

    If count = 1 Then
        cws.Cells(5, "a").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ElseIf count > 1 Then
        clastrow = cws.Cells(Rows.count, "a").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        cws.Cells(clastrow, "a").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If

    OpenClipboard (0&)
    EmptyClipboard
    CloseClipboard

    wb.Close

    fileName = Dir
    count = count + 1
Loop
'more code to fix data errors and formats
end sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transfer values directly with no copy/paste:

```
Do While fileName <> ""

    Set wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open(filePath & fileName)
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

    lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
    Set importRange = ws.Range("a2:f" & lastrow)

    clastrow = cws.Cells(Rows.count, "a").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    If clastrow < 5 then clastrow = 5

    'assign the range value directly 
    With importRange
        cws.Cells(clastrow, "a").Resize( _
              .rows.count, .columns.count).Value = .value
    End With  
    wb.Close False

    fileName = Dir
    count = count + 1
Loop
```